# I want to join the below mentioned queries into single query

Tags: mysql, join, select, query

```
SELECT
      A.update_date,
      A.create_user,
      A.service_id,A.order_id,
      '10009' AS main_plan_id,
      'Prepaid Cash' AS main_plan_name,
      ' ' AS topping_plan_id,
      ' ' AS topping_plan_name,
      '0' AS Price
FROM 
      ORDER_MASTER A 
WHERE 
      A.pending_order_type = 'Sim delivery' 
AND
      A.order_status='Pending' 
AND
      DATEDIFF(NOW(),update_date) > 30
GROUP BY 
      A.update_date,
      A.create_user,
      A.service_id,
      A.order_id,
      main_plan_id,
      main_plan_name,
      topping_plan_id,
      topping_plan_name;

SELECT
      A.update_date,
      A.create_user,
      A.service_id,
      A.order_id,
      ' ' AS main_plan_id,
      ' ' AS main_plan_name,
      D.topping_plan_id,
      D.topping_plan_name,
      D.charge_amount AS Price 
FROM 
      ORDER_MASTER A
LEFT JOIN
         (
           SELECT 
                 B.service_id AS service_id,
                 B.plan_id AS topping_plan_id,
                 B.plan_name AS topping_plan_name,
                 C.charge_amount charge_amount
           FROM 
                 BILLING.BS_SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION_MASTER B,
                 BILLING.BS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHARGE_DETAILS C
           WHERE 
                 B.subscription_id = C.subscription_id
         ) D
ON 
      A.service_id = D.service_id 
WHERE 
      A.pending_order_type='Sim delivery' 
AND
      A.order_status='Pending' 
AND
      DATEDIFF(NOW(),update_date) > 30 
GROUP BY
      A.update_date,
      A.create_user,
      A.service_id,
      A.order_id,
      main_plan_id,
      main_plan_name,
      D.topping_plan_id,
      D.topping_plan_name;
```

Comment: Formatting the code makes it much easier to understand, for reader as well as writer. What is the expected output of this join, what join predicate should be used etc?

Comment: In the first query I am printing main plan name,id,amount for a particular order and in the second query I am printing topping plan name,id,amount for that same order(say,a sub plan).  So for each order I want the main plan details to be printed in one row and then the sub plan details in the next row.

Comment: How does your second query select the same order as the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... )
```

The `GROUP BY` on the first `SELECT` seems to be useless; please explain why you have it.  I am less certain about the second query.

Not sargable: `DATEDIFF(NOW(),update_date) > 30`; change to `A.update_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY`.

Recommend:

```
A:  INDEX(order_status, pending_order_type, update_date)
C:  INDEX(subscription_id, charge_amount)
```

When `JOINing`, please use `FROM B JOIN C ON ...` instead of `FROM B, C WHERE ...`

(If you need further discussion, pleas provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)